# vxml element in ssml

Tags: attributes, element, vxml, ssml

i m just stuck with a vxml element in an ssml file in tropo. tropo does not recognize  
interpret="time" and i have to put interpret="vxml:time".  
But I need to also define the format attribute format:"hms12". so i write this:  
    `<say-as interpret-as="vxml:time" format="hms12">243P</say-as> </s>`

but it keeps pronouncing it like three integers.  
i searched everywhere for the right syntax but couldn't find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is the default format for Tropo.  Leave out the format attribute and make format your value as "0243p" for 2:43 PM, instead of "243P" as you have it.  If you do not have your value in the exact format from the source of the data I would just convert it to this format rather than trying to force Tropo to conform to its format.